# what is "modf()" (a math function from C/C++ etc.) shorthand for?

Tags: c++, c, math, terminology

In C and C++, the `modf` function can break floating number into fractional and integral parts.

I'm curious about what does "modf" stand for. What is it shorthand for?

Comment: Modulus float***

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez The `float` variant is actually named `modff`. `modf` is the `double` variant. So this doesn't seem right.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez `fmod()` (And friends) is the floating point modulus routine. I think the mod in `modf()` has to stand for something different, but I don't know what.

Comment: Apparently it differs from C to C++: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/modf-modff-modfl?view=vs-2019

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez That is just an additional overload in C++. The ones listed for C also apply to C++. The overloads were added later and can't have influenced the naming decision. Also as Shawn notes this is not the usual modulus function, making it less clear whether it really refers to "modulus" (though it still could).

Comment: @uneven_mark yep if you are looking for the remainder: `%`.

Comment: I'll vote for "mod" and "fraction".

Answer (score 2):

From the [Linux man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/modf):

> Name modf, modff, modfl - extract signed integral and fractional
>   values from floating-point number

Meaning that `modf` stands for **mod**ulus and **f**raction, as also @chux - Reinstate Monica suggested.

We can also read in the same page,

> Synopsis

```
#include <math.h>

double modf(double x, double *iptr);
float modff(float x, float, *iptr);
long double modfl(long double x, long double *iptr);
```

This makes clear that the f does not stand for `float`, but for fraction. This is for `C`, where `modf()` works on `double`s, `modff()` on `float`s and `modfl()` on `long double`s.

Answer (score 1):

> what is `modf()` shorthand for?

The function breaks a floating point number up into whole number and fractional parts.

Looking at the 1989 definition (I do not find it in K & R 1st Ed.)...

> The `modf` function break the argument `value` into integral and fractional parts, each of which has the same sign as the argument. It stores the integral part as a `double` in the object pointed to by `iptr`. The `modf` function returns the signed fractional part of `value`. [C89 7.5.4.6](https://www.pdf-archive.com/2014/10/02/ansi-iso-9899-1990-1/ansi-iso-9899-1990-1.pdf)

... has lead me to think of "mod" as the "left over" part which cannot be expressed with an integer and "f" as fraction to describe the returning value.  Could not call it `fmod()` as that is used for a `%` like function for `double`, nor plain `mod()` which is too integer like.

Sorry this in only based on my understanding since the late '80s.  Perhaps an 1960s/70s reference or guru can be found.

I suspect "mod" as the fractional remainder comes from Fortran of the 1970s, yet my reference books are [chest deep in the maze](https://rickadams.org/adventure/index.html).