# Is there a Math function to strip off decimals from a float (in Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a float like `32.879`, and I want to end up with just `0.879`, I can think of a few ways to do it, like:

- Convert to string, strip off everything before the `.`, convert back to float; OR
- `32.879 - int(32.879)`

Both of those feel like hacks. Is there no pure math operation that can do this?

Sort of like using `abs()` instead of `if x < 0: x = x*-1`

I'm dealing with Python, but if anyone can tell me the math name for this operation, I can probably google the Python way to do it.

Comment: `math.modf`, or see linked dupe.

Comment: Shortest way is `x%1`, but it depends what behaviour you expect for negative numbers.

Comment: @VisheshMangla converting a float to a string, doing string manipulation, and converting it back to a float is as inefficient, and hacky as it gets. Casting the number to an int, and subtracting it from the original is a roundabout way of doing it. `math.modf` is what I was looking for. Thanks guys

Comment: `abs(math.modf(x)[0])`. Seems to work fine. Is there a generic math name for this operation that isn't tied to any programming language?

Comment: @John if you only need the fractional part I'd also consider `x % 1` as a more concise way of expressing it. I'm not sure there's a generic term for it beyond "splitting into integer and fractional parts" -- `modf` is the name for this function for this in the original C math library. Maybe also see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986957/what-is-modf-a-math-function-from-c-c-etc-shorthand-for) for some etymology.

Comment: Yup - `x % 1` works too, and is shorter. Thanks guys!